# get only number from value and calculate the length from text field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I HAVE A TEXT FIELD

```
<input id="prime-phone" class="number-format" name="prime-phone" placeholder="" type="tel">
```

and there if fix value and it would be `"(432)432-2432"`.

I want to count the length of number only not the special character like "(" , "-"

I am trying in this way and i also know i am doing somthing wrong

```
sd = $(".number-format").val();
alert(sd);
sd = parseInt(sd)
alert(sd)
```

number format can be change like `"(432)432-2432"` , `"(43)-(432)-2432"`

Thanks
in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var sd = $(".number-format").val();
//i want to count the length of number only not the special character like "(" , "-"
var len = sd.match(/\d/g).length;
```

try it

Answer (score 1):

Use regex to match the digits and count:

```
sd.match(/\d/g).length
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove non digit character using [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and count

```
sd=$(".number-format").val();  
alert(sd);  
len=sd.replace(/\D/g,'').length;
// \D used to match all non-digit character
alert(len);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/qdj507dj/)

Answer (score 0):

A reusable solution.
once defined you could just call them to exclude the unwanted characters and get the length.i find this easier to maintain.

```
var tel = "(432)432-2432";    

var getLength = function(tel){
  var telStr = tel.split('');
  var excpetionList = ['(',')','-']; //<-- here you can add the chars to remove
  return telStr.filter(function(item,index,arr){
     if(excpetionList.indexOf(item) < 0){
       return item;
     }
  }).join('').length;
};

console.log(getLength(tel));
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/nosarosemava/1/edit)